# Why my coordinate (1,1) start at (0, 1)?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, line, render

I overriden Border control and in my overriden OnRender I do:

```
protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
        {
            this.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
            this.VisualEdgeMode = EdgeMode.Aliased;
            var myPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray), 1);
            dc.DrawLine(myPen, new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, RenderSize.Height - 1));
            return;
```

Which give me this result:
[image]

**Question:**

**Is anybody can tell me why my code draw a line that start at (0,1) while it is suppose to start at (1, 1) like written in code ?**

My DPI are 96, 96.

For ref, this is my xaml:

```
<Window xmlns:MyControls="clr-namespace:MyControls;assembly=MyControls"  x:Class="TestControls.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <MyControls:Border3D BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Aqua">
            <Rectangle Width="74" Height="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#40FF0000">

                    </SolidColorBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </MyControls:Border3D>

        <Rectangle  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="80" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: if you change your width to 526, does this behavior still happen?

Comment: It seems -i guess- you didn't calculate the border line ..so when you try to draw (1,1) you see on screeen as (0,1).. try this : new Point (1+ border.TopLine.Height, 1+border.LeftWall.width) NOTE : Given Code is PSEUDO, so probably there may not be find the Methods/Fields as the same name in .NET

Comment: Thanks. Clemens seems to have the exact answer to my answer, and I would say with a little nice extra explanation :-) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `(0, 0)` is not the center of the upper left pixel. Instead it is the upper left corner of that pixel. In order to draw a line with a stroke thickness of `1` in the middle of the second pixel column (with index 1) you would have to draw from `(1.5, 1)` to `(1.5, RenderSize.Height - 1)`:

```
dc.DrawLine(myPen, new Point(1.5, 1), new Point(1.5, RenderSize.Height - 1));
```

Setting `SnapsToDevicePixels = true` made your line snap to the left by half a pixel.

---

If you would use [PenLineCap.Square](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.penlinecap.aspx) for both the `StartLineCap` and `EndLineCap` properties of the line's Pen, you could draw from exactly one pixel center to the other:

```
var myPen = new Pen(Brushes.LightGray, 1);
myPen.StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Square;
myPen.EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Square;
dc.DrawLine(myPen, new Point(1.5, 1.5), new Point(1.5, RenderSize.Height - 1.5));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Clemens. Very clean explanation. I wonder if you have a suggestion of book to read to understand each and every aspect of the WPF drawing subtleties like those?

Comment: Adam Nathan's *WPF Unleashed* has a comprehensive chapter about 2D Graphics, which should give you a good starting point. There are also several detailed articles on MSDN.