# WPF line color is darker than its brush color

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, line

In my WPF application, I am using a line and some rectangles to make a graph. However, when I set the line to white, it appeared grey. I changed the line color to be the same as the red rectangle next to it and it is obvious that the line is darker. Here is my instantiation of the line and rectangle:

```
<Line Grid.Row="2" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="105" 
                  StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{StaticResource FgRedBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"
                  Margin="10 0 0 10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Width="100" Height="30"
                       Fill="{StaticResource FgGreenBrush}"
                       Margin="11 0 0 25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Width="170" Height="30" 
                       Fill="{StaticResource FgRedBrush}"
                       Margin="11 0 0 70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Also, here is a picture of the components: [image]

Nevermind the hardcoding, I am just getting a feel for the layout.

File with the definition of brush resources:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Financial_Manager.Colors">

<Color x:Key="ForegroundLight">#D7F6F6</Color>
<Color x:Key="ForegroundDark">#898989</Color>
<Color x:Key="ForegroundPurple">#D228FF</Color>
<Color x:Key="ForegroundBlue">#4DC6D2</Color>
<Color x:Key="ForegroundOrange">#F99D10</Color>
<Color x:Key="ForegroundGreen">#37AE53</Color>
<Color x:Key="ForegroundRed">#CE260B</Color>
<Color x:Key="ForegroundYellow">#CCFF00</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FgLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundLight}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FgDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundDark}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FgPurpleBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundPurple}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FgBlueBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundBlue}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FgOrangeBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundOrange}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FgGreenBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundGreen}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FgRedBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundRed}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FgYellowBrush" Color="{StaticResource ForegroundYellow}" />

<Color x:Key="BackgroundLight">#0D0A1C</Color>
<Color x:Key="BackgroundDark">#080610</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BgLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource BackgroundLight}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BgDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource BackgroundDark}" />
```

Comment: Can you include your resource file defining `fgRedBrush`?  Though it looks from your code that both stroke & fill use the same value, potentially you've got different definitions based on context (e.g. perhaps this value's defined twice; once for target type line, and once for target type rectangle.

Comment: I am updating the question with it

Comment: @JohnLBevan `{StaticResource FgRedBrush}` how should that be different, just because its used two times? There is no target type for a Brush resource.

Comment: Yeah it shouldn't matter but I included it just in case

Comment: There isn't by accident a default Style for Line that reduces its Opacity? How does it look with a thickness of 2 or more?

Comment: With 2+ thickness the brush returns to the proper color.

Comment: It's definitely an alignment/aliasing problem. Try to set LayoutRounding to false instead of true.

Comment: Also with opacity set to 1 it is still darker on a thickness of 1

Comment: I tried every combination of UseLayoutRounding and SnapsToDevicePixels with no luck

Comment: I'd just live with a thickness of 1.5 or 2.

Comment: I suppose that is the best option, though I do want to know why it does this. 1.5 thickness is closer to the proper color but still not there. Thanks anyways

Comment: Since coordinates are floating point values, you might also put the Line to the center of screen pixels by setting its X1 and X2 values to 0.5

Comment: @Clemens I was wondering if there may be multiple definitions / something like that in the resource file which may give another clue; since nothing in the definition explained the behaviour; so wanted to look elsewhere for more clues.  Sadly no joy there / looks like your `thickness` suggestion's the real issue.

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23488161/1136211

Comment: I posted a temporary fix in an answer but still want to know why

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Clemens in the comments, I have discovered that as the line thickness approaches 2, the color value approaches the true color. While I still don't know why and would be open to learning, a temporary fix is to set the thickness to 1.99 so that the color *appears* the same. While the thickness is essentially 2, it still has the same visual appearance as 1.

Comment: Have you tried to set X1 and X2 to 0.5? Possibly also `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"`.